# In Laravel how to use git ignore to ignore public subfolder

Tags: laravel, git

I have created one git repository for my Laravel application in that I want to prevent public/Customer folder to push in git repository for that I have added /public/Customer/ path in .gitignore file but it is not working

Comment: Did you pushed `.gitignore` to your repo already?

Comment: Have you already commited files in that path?

Comment: yes i have already commited .gitignore file

Answer (score 1):

In your `.gitignore` file you need to add this line

```
/public/Customer/
```

If you want to lets say just ignore the images you can add this line

```
/public/Customer/*.jpg
/public/Customer/*.png
```

Comment: My customer folder again have two subfolder i want to ignore that.

Comment: /public/Customer/ will ignore everything that is in that folder, no matter how many subfolders you have, if you want to ignore just one add the name of that subfolder to /public/Customer/...